# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 005XXXXXXXXXXXX)

Tags: community, sharing, user, apex-sharing, sharerecord

I've a object called `myobject__c`. This object is private in OWD Setting.

Now when admin create a new record of this object then I want to share this record with a user(community user). For this I've written a code in trigger to create a sharing record of this object (`myobject__Share`).

But I am getting a problem of :-

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception: unknown (invalid
>   user or group: 005XXXXXXXXXXXXX).

how can I solve this problem and second doubt is can we create share record for community user or not.

Comment: What type of Communities user license is it, Customer or Partner?

Comment: The license type is Customer Community Login.

Answer (score 16):

Customer Communities users do not have access to the full sharing model and therefore can't be added on a __Share record. The only way to share a record with a Customer Communities user is through Sharing Sets and Sharing Groups.

Comment: I believe Customer Community Plus users can participate in the full sharing model.

Comment: Customer Communites Plus licenses do have access to the sharing model, and my answer should be revised as these licenses did not exist in 2014 when this answer was posted.