# Customer Community Using Apex Sharing

Tags: customer-community, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I am trying record sharing through apex. But when i am giving sharing setting to Customer Community User it is throwing this exception

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 00528000002WuKu):

So how can i Share records for Community User. I am having License **Customer Community** and I have created one Custom Profile called **Hudson Changes**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Customer Communities users do not have access to the full sharing
>   model and therefore can't be added on a __Share record. The only way
>   to share a record with a Customer Communities user is through Sharing
>   Sets and Sharing Groups.

**[Source](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44728/field-integrity-exception-field-integrity-exception-unknown-invalid-user-or-g)**

Comment: Ratan is right, and the workaround we used to get more flexibility than sharing sets and sharing groups was to set the records to be generally hidden from community users, then implement Visualforce Controllers "without sharing" which could serve up the records that we wanted to share with Apex Sharing Rules. Tedious, but effective if you don't have too many pages to worry about.